# PHP OnClick Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've got a while loop to build a table of data and onclick I want to call a function but when I the function is called it's not getting the info from the onclick being passed.

HTML:

```
echo "<td width='25%' align='center'><a href='javascript:void(0)' id='{$row['id']}' class='{$row['status']}' onclick='hello()'> {$row['status']} </a></td>";
```

JS:

```
//onclick function
function hello()
{
   // Get the ID of the button that was clicked on
   var id_of_status_to_update = $(this).attr("id");
   var status_to_be_updated = $(this).attr("class");
   var varData = 'id=' + id_of_status_to_update + '&UserStatus=' + 
   status_to_be_updated;
   console.log(varData);

   // Make an AJAX request
   $.ajax({
      url: "php/processor.php", //This is the page where you will handle your SQL insert
      type: "POST",
      data: varData, //The data your sending to processor.php
      async: false, 
      success: function(){
          // location.reload();
          alert("Hello Function");
      },
      error: function(){
          alert("There was a problem, please try again or contact the admin for assistance.");
      }   
    });
};
```

but when I check the console log I'm seeing the id and userstatus are undefined instead of what should be the passed attributes of id and class. Any help? I know the function is being called properly because I'm getting the success alert.

Comment: try taking a variable in the function arg, like`function hello(event)`, and replace the this with event

Comment: The HTTP response might be 2xx, but that doesn't mean that the PHP script is doing what you expect. Could you share that, too?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the ancient `onclick` method, and use a proper jquery `.click` event handler, and then your use of `$(this)` will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your undefined issue, remove the ancient onclick method, and use a proper jquery `.click` event handler, and then your use of `$(this)` will work properly.

First adjust your html build to this:

```
echo "<td width='25%' align='center'><a href='#' id='{$row['id']}' class='clicker {$row['status']}'> {$row['status']} </a></td>";
```

Then adjust the javascript a bit to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clicker").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // new line to stop the anchor click default behavior
        var id_of_status_to_update = $(this).attr("id");
        var status_to_be_updated = $(this).attr("class");
        // ... the rest you had is fine as is ...
    });
});
```

This attaches a click event handler to the class if "clicker", so it applies to all buttons with that class.

Comment: I had it like that originally - but then I need a unique id - because there is like 70 rows that would have the same id and I could only get the first row working.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions and let you know how that works.

Comment: This is why you use the `class` for the event hook, not the `id`. And when a button is clicked then `$(this)` refers to only the button that was clicked to fire off that event :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
$('#id').on('click', function(){
//Do something
//console.log(this)
})
```

Of course you would need to pass the element a fixed id, alternatively you can use $('.class') and pass it a class instead!

Answer (score 0):

because the `this` inside function `hello` points to the `window` object. you can pass an `event` parameter to the `hello` function like `onclick="hello(event)"` and inside this function, you can use `event.target.getAttribute('id')` to access this element's id, don't forget to change the function definition `function hello(){...}` to `function hello(event){...}`